# ControlsFX HiddenSidesPane hides When clicked

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I am using `ControlsFX - HiddenSidesPane` where i add some link(`ToggleButton`s) to be clicked for navigation.

The problem i have is whenever anything is clicked, the `HiddenSiddesPane` hides.

The desired behavior is when anything inside it is clicked it should not close/hide, unless cursor hovers out of it.

`SSCCE` to demonstrate undesired behavior

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.HiddenSidesPane;

public class MyHiddenSidesPaneDemo  extends Application{
public static void main(String[] args) { Application.launch(args); }

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    TableView tv = new TableView();
    HiddenSidesPane hiddenSidesPane = new HiddenSidesPane();
    hiddenSidesPane.setContent(tv);
    hiddenSidesPane.setLeft(new ListView());
    root.getChildren().addAll(hiddenSidesPane);
    primaryStage.setTitle("HiddenSidesPane Example Demo");
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ListView listView = new ListView();
hiddenSidesPane.setLeft(listView);

listView.setOnMouseEntered(e->hiddenSidesPane.setPinnedSide(Side.LEFT)); //Keep left side pinned
listView.setOnMouseExited(e->hiddenSidesPane.setPinnedSide(null)); //unpin when mouse exits
```